# Multiple aggregation whit case when in group by in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how to translate the sql by pandas :

```
select count(case new=='A' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as score1 
        ,sum(s*s2) as score2 
  from table
 group by u1;
```

the dataframe like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'s':[5,2,1,3],
               's2':[1,2,1,2],
               'new':list('ABAB'),
               'u1':list('WWYY'),
               'u2':list('abab')})

   new  s  s2 u1 u2
0   A  5   1  W  a
1   B  2   2  W  b
2   A  1   1  Y  a
3   B  3   2  Y  b
```

the final result like this :

```
   u1  score1  score2  
0   W   0.5     9
1   Y   0.5     7
```

Comment: I dont understand `score2`, can you explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html), but first create new columns:

```
#convert boolean mask to int
df['score1'] = (df.new == 'A').astype(int)
#multiple s and s2 columns
df['score2'] = df.s.mul(df.s2)
print (df)
  new  s  s2 u1 u2  score1  score2
0   A  5   1  W  a       1       5
1   B  2   2  W  b       0       4
2   A  1   1  Y  a       1       1
3   B  3   2  Y  b       0       6

df = df.groupby('u1').agg({'score1':'mean', 'score2':'sum'})
print (df)
    score1  score2
u1                
W      0.5       9
Y      0.5       7
```

Comment: oh, I got it. I should do some pre-treatment then do simple mean or sum !Thank you very much!

Comment: the score2 is correct !  the result I wrote before was count in my head,and I've got a wrong answer……

Comment: Super, no problem.